# c# Mongo db FindAll()

Tags: c#, mongodb, findall

I am new at MongoDB and C#. I don't know how to get all data from my collection "kljenti".

Can anybody help me?

Below is my code

```
 public void getAllData() {
 try {
     string connectionString = "mongodb://172.16.1.24:27017";
     MongoClient client = null;
     client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
     MongoServer server = null;
     server = client.GetServer();
     MongoDatabase database = null;
     database = server.GetDatabase("kljenti");
     var Client = new MongoClient();
     var DB = Client.GetDatabase("knjigoMata");
     var collection = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("kljenti");
     MongoCursor < BsonDocument > cursor = collection.FindAllAs<BsonDocument>();
     } 
catch{
     MessageBox.Show("Nemogu prikazati podatke o korisnicima");
      }
```

Comment: Looks like you're already getting all the data. You just need to iterate through the cursor

Comment: If you plan to work with Mongo, consider to take a great cource https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101N/about

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

> var allDocuments = collection.Find(new
>   BsonDocument()).ToListAsync().Result;

Comment: sorry can you expain me why we need to write new BsonDocument()?

Comment: i have a nother question :  i need to call this method getAllAdata in another form, what kind of type sholud be a method, and what will be a return ?

Comment: @MatijaDomjan 1. new BsonDocument() just means no filter. 2. What do you mean saying another form? mapped to you c# class? If so, you need to have a class Client and  use it `var collection = DB.GetCollection<Client>("kljenti");` The rest should be the same.